# Ideal Setup for Swiss-Style Quotes (Quotation Marks in German-speaking Switzerland)

Tags: punctuation

As far as I know Switzerland uses French quotes but without whitespace.
So instead of

```
« citation »
```

it goes like this

```
«citation»
```

(to make it more confusing, in Germany they have the alternative use of `»citation«`)

I am going quite well with the double quotes because on one side I do find them on my Swiss keyboard (AltGr+y/x) and there is also a nice way on English or German keyboards which then gets rendered

```
<<citation>>
```

So the first question actually is if it is fine to just use the French quotes without spaces. Typographically there is quite some difference. Do I completely mess it up by just miss-using this stuff for Swiss citation?

I also do have a problem with the single quotes.

```
‹ french › and ‹swiss›
```

I don't find them on my keyboard and simply use of English keys like `<cite>` does not work either. What I do for now is just copy and paste the original letters which I copied from wikipedia. Of course I can also use `\flq` and `\frq` (or `\frqq` and `\flqq` for double quotes) but this does still not answer the above question.

So again:

- Any ideas and hints for simplifying single quotes?
- Is the approach of turned French quotes the right solution at all for Swiss style?

Or in general terms: What would be a recommended ideal setup for Swiss quotations?

Comment: Check out the `csquotes` package. This can do everything you want, I should think.

Comment: I wanted to look your hint up and create an answer myself, but the answers came so fast I had not even a chance to do so! As I just found the solution it already was to late. Stackexchange is to awesome to actually have a chance to write your own solution down. If you put some effort into your question it gets fixed in more then a short coffee break :-) So: Thanks for your answer, it also gave me the solution on a parallel way ;-)

Comment: It seems that you somehow got confused about French usage. French used (double only) quotes like this : « quoted text », with unbreakable spaces between quotes and quoted text. This is taken care of by babel and the frenchb option which provides \og and and \fg commands to open and close quote marks. If other quote marks are needed (e.g. for quote within quote), the british curly quotes would be used.

See for instance http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillemet.

Comment: @BorisDäppen On an unrelated note: Within the wider context of [Mico's upcoming package `selnolig`](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2884/4012), I'm looking for official/good resources on Swiss (and Austrian) spelling conventions. (I'm aware of the Swiss abandonment of 'ß', but that's about all I know.) Do you happen to be able to point me to anything on this topic? (We can set up a room in [chat] if we're going to go into more detail.)

Comment: @doncherry - I am Swiss citizen, but I'm not much an expert in such things. I don't think I can give any valid information. If you have a specific question you may ask me in a private message and I can see if find something about it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could use the `csquotes` package. Together with the `babel` package it should take care of the quotes automatically (cf. example below).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[german=swiss]{csquotes}
\begin{document}
    \enquote{Text \enquote{Quote in quote} more text}
\end{document}
```

This renders as:

[image]

As pointed out in the comments, adding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` improves the rendering of the quotes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[german=swiss]{csquotes}
\begin{document}
    \enquote{Text \enquote{Quote in quote} more text}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Additionally to the context sensitive way, single quotes can also be set explicitly (if needed on first level):

```
\enquote*{Enforced single quotes}
```

Comment: The quotes look awfull. Add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

Comment: I'm not sure if this should be included into the "minimal example" of the answer. But for sure this comment must be up-voted, because it is helpful in that context! I also used the setting before asking my question.

Comment: @BorisDäppen I'd definitely add `T1` to the minimal answer. In the OT1 encoding the guillemets are simply awful.

Comment: I decided to do some diplomatic way... Additional to the first really minimal example I put another one that shows the improvement that fontenc does.

Comment: @BenediktBauer We generally agree to do "improvements" in the answers. The answer needn't be minimal, so since it's obviously better to use `T1`, it's good to do so in the answer as well ;)

Answer (score 15):

You could use the `csquotes`-package. This would be a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[german=swiss]{csquotes}
\begin{document}
\enquote{Dies ist ein Zitat}
\end{document}
```

For more options check the documentation of `csquotes`.

Comment: Sorry for accepting the other one. You actually where first :-( Well, maybe the picture he mentioned helps others to understand the example more easily. Thanks a lot for your help!